# Remove all attributes from every element inside a div

Tags: jquery

I need to remove all attributes (ids, classes, events, styles etc.) from every element inside a `<div>`.

How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use the .removeAttr function

Comment: Answers there are but I would recommend looking into [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) and [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) to learn more.

Comment: @Amit Yes I have tried a few things but didnt paste any code as I was travelling to work and posted the question via my mobile. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using a simple while loop:

```
$("div#myDiv").children().each(function() {
    while(this.attributes.length > 0)
        this.removeAttribute(this.attributes[0].name);
});
```

Where 'myDiv' is the ID of the parent div.